# what is the effect of *pe=pn->Entry;?

Tags: c

All I need to understand is what is that line mean:

```
*pe=pn->Entry;
```

Why can't I skip it.how does it affect the serve operation?

```
void Serve(Entrytype *pe,Queue *pq){
    QueueNode *pn;
    *pe=pn->Entry;
    pn=pq->front;
    pq->front=pn->next;
    free(pn);
}
```

Comment: Hint: If you want to alter the caller's variable `pe`, this is how you do it.

Comment: `*pe = pn->Entry` assigns the value of `pn->Entry` to the object addressed by `pe`.  That's what `=` does.

Comment: This code is wrong because it dereferences the uninitialized pointer `pn`.

Comment: Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't affect the function itself, however it essentially acts as a return value, setting a value outside the function denoted by the pointer for later use. So, if you omit the line, the function will still work, but what comes after the function might not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common C technique to allow for mutable arguments. A typical case looks like this:

```
void mutate(int* a) {
  *a = 5;
}
```

Where when called:

```
int main() {
  int a = 0;
  mutate(&a);
  printf("a=%d\n", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Will now show that `a` has been altered.

If this were a non-pointer argument, like this:

```
void mutate(int a) {
  a = 5;
}
```

Then you're only changing the local variable `a` and it has no effect on the caller's variable.